# Typescipt: Define Type by parameters supplied

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces:

```
interface RequestCallWithBody {
  method?: 'GET' | 'DELETE' | 'HEAD' | 'OPTIONS' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'LINK' | 'UNLINK';
  headers?: object;
  body?: object; // ------------- it have body //
  params?: object;
  noValidate?: boolean;
  returnFullResponse?: boolean;
}

interface RequestCallWithForm {
  method?: 'GET' | 'DELETE' | 'HEAD' | 'OPTIONS' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'LINK' | 'UNLINK';
  headers?: object;
  form?: object; // ------------- it have form //
  params?: object;
  noValidate?: boolean;
  returnFullResponse?: boolean;
}
```

I use that two interface as a union type in a function:

```
async call<T>(url: string, config?: RequestCallWithBody | RequestCallWithForm): Promise<T> {}
```

However, when I call the function, I get no error when I supply `body` and `form` on the params:

```
await call<object>(
    URL, 
    { form: {}, body: {} } // ------------- i got no error
)
```

Is this expected behavior of union type? If so, how can I limit the params in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. Excess property checking allows properties to be present if they properly match some constituents in the target(the union). You can find more information here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38144, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38024.

Answer (score 0):

As @gqstav mentioned in his answer, the type is not enforced for the union.

You can use overloading as a workaround:

```js
function call<T>(url: string, config?: RequestCallWithBody): Promise<T>
function call<T>(url: string, config?: RequestCallWithForm): Promise<T>
async function call<T>(url: string, config?: RequestCallWithBody | RequestCallWithForm): Promise<T> {
    ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=27&ssc=25&pln=27&pc=15#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4FcIGcwDCcANsQOrBgAWAQgPYAmAnsgN4BQyyAthNYwH4AXMgDkAcQCiAFVHIAPmIAikgDIzJcxaIASkgIJKtYgPIAFaQEkTAOQDKx0WZN3ZCsWYCqb7Wf3SCHUdVSxsAaUdPGxDw0QBuTmQqCDgGaFxhZDoAIwArCAQwBK5sxiZMnPzCuOQAelrkAFpmltaW5EokuAA3FFLmOtrEgAc4KDhuDJFKgqLEkDoANRJgBjhITNK6YhSQYuQoPiwoEAAxLFJ0XGG6EFwITbpt3YSAX3Z2UEhYRBR0bDwhBI5EoVFOdCg3DYiV4-AYmQkMkcKnU0k07l0BiMGPMVlsDgxzlcji8Pg8-kCwVCEQxURiEX2yVS6QqeVm%20xgEO4rKqRUGTTagsaHTAXV6yE5kMGIzGEymWTZ1XmSxWaw2Ii2Ozge0ShzAxzOF2IVxudweGqeWp173YMCwIEKwFuyAQwIAPNIAHwACmOxBE%20CgoAA5gAaF23GDAYOZf44fBEUgUaj0ZgAShEZigdG4wHuHs9tvtjudrtIBd9UH9yEDIfDCEj0djmHjQKToPBkIzyCzObzEAL7DguCYDolxbATpALvdXsr1drIDDEZAUZjIjjgMTIJTZXcm4TwOTYK53d7ufzXuhXC4eoNbFeyGHT5ATDeHzLxG9iS4ACJf6GP5sBKXIiKwrzhv0TBgY%207xpnEQA)